# java spring boot app deployment on jboss 7.2 error: nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/reactivestreams/Publisher

Tags: spring-boot, azure, jboss, reactive-streams, azure-spring-cloud

I am trying to deploy spring boot app in java 8 on jboss 7.2
I got this error when I am trying to deploy war file into jboss standalone deployments

```
Error creating bean with name 'springCloudAzureDefaultCredential' defined in class path resource [com/azure/spring/cloud/autoconfigure/context/AzureTokenCredentialAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'tokenCredential' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'azureCredentialBuilderFactory' defined in class path resource [com/azure/spring/cloud/autoconfigure/context/AzureTokenCredentialAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.azure.spring.cloud.core.implementation.factory.credential.DefaultAzureCredentialBuilderFactory]: Factory method 'azureCredentialBuilderFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/reactivestreams/Publisher
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'azureCredentialBuilderFactory' defined in class path resource [com/azure/spring/cloud/autoconfigure/context/AzureTokenCredentialAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.azure.spring.cloud.core.implementation.factory.credential.DefaultAzureCredentialBuilderFactory]: Factory method 'azureCredentialBuilderFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/reactivestreams/Publisher
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.azure.spring.cloud.core.implementation.factory.credential.DefaultAzureCredentialBuilderFactory]: Factory method 'azureCredentialBuilderFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/reactivestreams/Publisher
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/reactivestreams/Publisher
```

My pom file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud-azure.version>4.6.0</spring-cloud-azure.version>
        <!--<deploy.wildfly.host>127.0.0.1</deploy.wildfly.host>
        <deploy.wildfly.port>9990</deploy.wildfly.port>
        <deploy.wildfly.username>wildfly</deploy.wildfly.username>
        <deploy.wildfly.password>w1ldFly!</deploy.wildfly.password> -->
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-storage</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-storage-file-share</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-storage-blob</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <!--<optional>true</optional>-->
            <version>1.18.30</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-azure.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <!--<build>
        <finalName>springbootwildfly</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2.Final</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <hostname>${deploy.wildfly.host}</hostname>
                    <port>${deploy.wildfly.port}</port>
                    <username>${deploy.wildfly.username}</username>
                    <password>${deploy.wildfly.password}</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>-->

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2.Final</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I tried to add reactivestreams to pom file but it did not work ( versions 1.0.0 and 1.0.4)

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactive-streams</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I also tried with azure spring cloud version 4.13.0 because I found that it could be wrong version problem but nothing works

This is dependency tree

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.17.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.17.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.36:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.22:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.22:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.3.22:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.22:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.22:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.22:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.7.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.65:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.65:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.65:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.7.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.7.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.7.3:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.4.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.22.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.8.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.8.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.8.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.8.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.8.2:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.8.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:4.5.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.12.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.12.13:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:4.5.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.22:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.22:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.3.22:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.9.0:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.2.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:4.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.3.22:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.transaction:jakarta.transaction-api:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.6.10.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.4.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.1.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.12:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:1.2.2:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.3.22:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.3.22:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.3.22:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-starter:jar:4.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-autoconfigure:jar:4.6.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-service:jar:4.6.0:compile
[INFO] |        \- com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-core:jar:4.6.0:compile
[INFO] |           +- com.azure:azure-identity:jar:1.7.3:compile
[INFO] |           |  +- com.microsoft.azure:msal4j:jar:1.13.3:compile
[INFO] |           |  |  \- com.nimbusds:oauth2-oidc-sdk:jar:9.35:compile
[INFO] |           |  |     +- com.github.stephenc.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0-1:compile
[INFO] |           |  |     +- com.nimbusds:content-type:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |           |  |     +- com.nimbusds:lang-tag:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |           |  |     \- com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:jar:9.22:compile
[INFO] |           |  +- com.microsoft.azure:msal4j-persistence-extension:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |           |  |  \- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |           |  \- net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:jar:5.6.0:compile
[INFO] |           +- com.azure:azure-core-amqp:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] |           |  +- com.microsoft.azure:qpid-proton-j-extensions:jar:1.2.4:compile
[INFO] |           |  \- org.apache.qpid:proton-j:jar:0.33.8:compile
[INFO] |           \- com.azure:azure-core-management:jar:1.10.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-starter-storage:jar:4.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-starter-storage-queue:jar:4.6.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.azure:azure-storage-queue:jar:12.15.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-starter-storage-file-share:jar:4.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.azure:azure-storage-file-share:jar:12.16.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.azure:azure-core:jar:1.35.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.4.22:compile
[INFO] |     |     \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.azure:azure-core-http-netty:jar:1.12.8:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.79.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.79.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.79.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.79.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.79.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.79.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.79.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.79.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.79.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.79.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.79.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.79.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-classes-epoll:jar:4.1.79.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-kqueue:jar:osx-x86_64:4.1.79.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-classes-kqueue:jar:4.1.79.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:2.0.53.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- io.netty:netty-tcnative-classes:jar:2.0.53.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:linux-x86_64:2.0.53.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:linux-aarch_64:2.0.53.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:osx-x86_64:2.0.53.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:osx-aarch_64:2.0.53.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:windows-x86_64:2.0.53.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |     |     +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns:jar:4.1.79.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |     |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-dns:jar:4.1.79.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |     +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos:jar:osx-x86_64:4.1.79.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |     |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-classes-macos:jar:4.1.79.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |     \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-core:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.azure:azure-storage-common:jar:12.19.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:4.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:6.4.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-starter-storage-blob:jar:4.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.azure:azure-storage-blob:jar:12.20.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.azure:azure-storage-internal-avro:jar:12.5.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:2.1.214:runtime
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.30:provided
[INFO] \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.9.0:compile
```

Comment: Hi, is it working on localhost when trying it locally ? can you make sure that the necessary libraries are included in the JBoss deployment or module configuration? can you share the jboss config ? and the docker configuration